# OpenGL TES, possible to have adjacency information in output?

Tags: opengl, geometry-shader, tessellation

I am wondering whether a Tessellation Evaluation Shader (TES) can somehow output adjacency information that can then be used by a Geometry Shader (GS).

Let's take as example a TCS/TES combination rendering some isocurves using `layout (isolines, equal_spacing, ccw) in`. Subsequently using `layout (lines) in` in the GS works, though `layout (lines_adjacency) in` does not. I know that adjacency information has to be provided explicitly in the case where no TCS/TES are present (e.g. using an updated list of indices and `glDrawElements` using `GL_LINES_ADJACENCY`), but is there a way to let the TES generate this information? Reading [this section](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Tessellation#Primitive_generation_order) it seems that this information cannot be generated automatically — hopefully I'm overlooking something.

The application that I have in mind is to draw thick smooth curves, i.e. first generating lots of vertices and connecting them with line segments using tessellation, and subsequently replacing these line segments by triangle strips like explained [here](https://forum.libcinder.org/topic/smooth-thick-lines-using-geometry-shader).

A very similar question has been asked before [here](https://www.opengl.org/discussion_boards/showthread.php/172932-Adjacency-primitives-from-tessellation-output), so far without conclusive answer.

Answer (score 0):

The tessellation primitive generator only generates sequences of point, line, or triangle primitives, based on the [abstract patch type](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Tessellation#Abstract_patch) and `point_mode` generation. It never generates strips/fans/lists, and certainly not adjacency primitives.

What you want would be better handled by having the TES generate additional per-vertex data, which the GS will use to do whatever you wanted the adjacency information for.